# how to replace ' with ' ' in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have some code that creates stored procedure and send it to SQL DB, on of the parameters is filename, one of the files include the character '

I'm trying to replace ' with '' in C# with no luck,

ANy help,

Comment: Use parameterised SQL!

Comment: Post some of your code.  We can't help you if we don't know what you've tried so far.

Comment: You should look for a stored procedure solution

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

```
String myString = "'foo'";
myString = mySTring.Replace("'", "''");
```

I'm willing to bet you're calling the same replace method, but not storing the results back into the original string. Don't forget, Strings are immutable. The methods on a string don't manipulate the string itself, but rather return the modified string.

Long Answer:
You should be using parameters in your query instead of what you're trying to do. Parameterizing your parameters makes your code a lot cleaner by removing the need for the replace calls above. It also make your queries more secure by preventing injection attacks/mistakes.

```
SqlCommand query = myConnection.CreateCommand();
query.CommandText =  "SELECT * FROM myTable where name = @name";
query.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter( "name", "john" ) );
```

Comment: +1 - for using parameterized queries... Would like to see you explain _why_ they are better.

Comment: @Oded, Bobby Tables provides courses in why they are better. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Paul I was thinking of just that comic too!

Answer (score 0):

string fileName="";
fileName = fileName.Replace("'", "\"");

Answer (score 0):

[how to insert data if it contain apostrophe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703406/how-to-insert-data-if-it-contain-apostrophe)

**Similar question was asked before. Take a look.**

Dont just replace the ' with something, then it will be a target of sql injection. :(